# Expected Semi colon Ajax - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have an ajax request and its giving me an **"Expected ;"** error.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").bind("click", function () {
                var ids[] = null;
                var dates[] = null;
                createUpdateArrays();
                var url = "/hello/index/";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: url,
                    data: { ids: ids, dates: dates },
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (success) {
                        if (success === true) {
                            alert("HERE WE ARE");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("eror")
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert("eror")
                    }
                });
            });
            createUpdateArrays() {  // Expected ; <---- here
                $('.id').each(function(i) {
                    var rid = $(this).id;
                    $('.planned-date').each(function(x) {
                        if (i===x) {
                            var date = $(this).text;
                            ids.push(rid);
                            dates.push(date);
                        }

                    });
                });
            }; // <--- this is where the createUpdateArrays function ends. 
        });
```

I pointed where the error occurs in the code. I don't understand what it is, I feel that I am syntactically correct. I placed the semi colon where the function ends. If anyone can help, that would be great. I feel like its a minor mistake or I am missing something. Thank you.

Comment: You might need to add `function` for `createUpdateArrays()` and invoke it else

Comment: You're missing the `function` keyword on that line

Comment: This is not the way we create functions. you should use `function createUpdateArrays() {  // your code }`

Comment: Also, remove `async: false`. It's terrible practice

Comment: That worked @lucumt thanks!

Comment: Why so @RoryMcCrossan?

Comment: @caitlinp Glad to help you,can you mark my answer as accepted or upvote it?

Comment: Mainly because it blocks the browser UI from updating while the request is processing. As such, the browser will appear to the user as though it has hung/crashed. Also note that you're best to just delete this question as it was a simple typo that caused the problem.

Comment: Ahh I see thank you @RoryMcCrossan. Also, Stack won't let me delete this question lol..

Comment: Also, why do the var ids[] = null; var dates[] = null; expect a semicolon? I am also getting a error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already you cant push anything to  ids and dates from your createUpdatesArray function. Because ids and dates not defined as global variables. Your post function will always send null because of this. You need to change your code little bit. 
You can define ids and dates  like :

```
var ids = {};
var dates = {};
```

Remember that , now your function and "ids, dates" not under same scope. so you cant push anything to them from createUpdatesArray function. 
You must define this items between `<script>` and `document.ready` function.

Your last code will looks like :

```
var ids = {}; // ids is global now.
var dates = {}; // dates is global now.

$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnSubmit").bind("click", function () {
                    //var ids[] = null;
                    //var dates[] = null;
                    createUpdateArrays();
                    var url = "/hello/index/";
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Post",
                        url: url,
                        data: { ids: ids, dates: dates },
                        async: false,
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (success) {
                            if (success === true) {
                                alert("HERE WE ARE");
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("eror");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (e) {
                            alert("eror");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

    function createUpdateArrays() {  // Expected ; <---- here
                    $('.remedy-id').each(function(i) {
                        var rid = $(this).id;
                        $('.planned-date').each(function(x) {
                            if (i===x) {
                                var date = $(this).text;
                                ids.push(rid);
                                dates.push(date);
                            }

                        });
                    });
                }; // <--- this is where the createUpdateArrays function ends.
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare creatUpdateArrays as a function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").bind("click", function () {
                var ids[] = null;
                var dates[] = null;
                createUpdateArrays();
                var url = "/hello/index/";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: url,
                    data: { ids: ids, dates: dates },
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (success) {
                        if (success === true) {
                            alert("HERE WE ARE");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("eror")
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert("eror")
                    }
                });
            });
            function createUpdateArrays() {  // Expected ; <---- here
                $('.remedy-id').each(function (i) {
                    var rid = $(this).id;
                    $('.planned-date').each(function (x) {
                        if (i === x) {
                            var date = $(this).text;
                            ids.push(rid);
                            dates.push(date);
                        }

                    });
                });
            };  
        });
```

Or even declare the function outside of your document ready and just reference the function in the ready.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").bind("click", function () {
                var ids[] = null;
                var dates[] = null;
                createUpdateArrays();
                var url = "/hello/index/";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: url,
                    data: { ids: ids, dates: dates },
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (success) {
                        if (success === true) {
                            alert("HERE WE ARE");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("eror")
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert("eror")
                    }
                });
            });
        });

function createUpdateArrays() {  // Expected ; <---- here
                $('.remedy-id').each(function(i) {
                    var rid = $(this).id;
                    $('.planned-date').each(function(x) {
                        if (i===x) {
                            var date = $(this).text;
                            ids.push(rid);
                            dates.push(date);
                        }

                    });
                });
            }; // <--- this is where the createUpdateArrays function ends.
```

Try this.

Its because you are missing "function" keyword, you should use it for define a function.

Comment: Also, why do the var ids[] = null;     var dates[] = null;   expect a semicolon? I am also getting a error there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `function` for `createUpdateArrays()` and define it outside `$(document).ready()`

```
function createUpdateArrays() {  // Expected ; <---- here
                $('.remedy-id').each(function(i) {
                    var rid = $(this).id;
                    $('.planned-date').each(function(x) {
                        if (i===x) {
                            var date = $(this).text;
                            ids.push(rid);
                            dates.push(date);
                        }

                    });
                });
            }; // <--
```